# How to get variables in for loops to update properly

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch file that contains this:

```
@echo off
set /a count=0
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (a.txt) do (
   set /a count+=1
   echo %count% : %%a
)
echo %count%
```

And a.txt contains this:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

I **expect** the output to look something like this:

```
1 : 1
2 : 2
3 : 3
4 : 4
5 : 5
5
```

But instead I get:

```
0 : 1
0 : 2
0 : 3
0 : 4
0 : 5
5
```

So as you can see - the file is parsing correctly, the count is working (you can see that `%count%` is equal to 5 at the end) but for some reason, %count% stays at 0 until after the loop.

How do I get variables that update inside a for loop to actually be usable within that for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
echo %count% : %%a
```

To this else:

```
Call echo %%count%% : %%a
```

Or use the variable expansion:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /a count=0
for /F "tokens=*" %%a in (a.txt) do (
   set /a count+=1
   echo !count! : %%a
)
echo %count%
```

**Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion**: http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html

Comment: :D using `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` and `!` instead of `%` did the trick. Thanks heaps :D

Comment: I might add that the first options (using call) did not work for me.

Comment: The call solution works, at least on Win7.

Comment: I tried on both Win8 and Win08 server. *shrug* Maybe other people will have more luck with it.

Comment: Are you sure you enclose the variable in _two_ percents signs?